# ajax Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: ajax, angularjs, codeigniter, http, http-headers

So I have my dev server at d2.websta.me and also I have another url https://websta.me and I have backend functions that I want to use inside d2.websta.me

I am using codeigniter for my backend and angularjs on frontend

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,Origin,Accept');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://websta.me');
```

I already put this tons of header but still I get the error Content-Type is not Allowed by access-control-allow headers..

Did I do something wrong? or Do I have to edit these headers? Or how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

from php side -> backend server
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your-front-end-url-here');

from angular side

return $http({
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                            url: 'your-back-end-url-here',
                            method: "POST",
                            data: $params
                        })

should work

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send request from one domain to another, you should use curl and not the regular request like you use in requests to the same domain.
And in your case it is two different domains.

Update: it is for server-server requests.
Can you please post here your ajax code?

Comment: hi thanks for taking time to answer the question. As I have said, I am using Angularjs so I can use $http but the problem is I cannot send or receive data from other domain because of cross origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

the way I mentioned previously actually works between 2 different domains.

I have my frontend located on on domain.com and backend on my backenddomain.com
and have no problem to send and receive data. For calls from frontend to API on backend you don't need curl -> it is not a connection between 2 php scripts on 2 servers. Actually even then curl is not absolutely necessary.